# How do I convert a dynamic, pointer-based int stack so it prints out as a string?

Tags: c++, stack

I am creating a reverse Polish notation integer calculator in c++ by writing a dynamic, pointer-based stack, but I am having trouble with the toString method in the MyStack class.

here is a bit of background of how my code is supposed to work:

## Method descriptions:

- `constructor`:   Initializes the object, setting up necessary memory.
- `destructor`:   Frees any memory that may need freeing by the object.
- `clear()`:   Empties the stack.
- `pop()`:   Removes and returns the top value on the stack, if it is not empty.   Throws an exception if the stack is empty when trying to pop.  Choose any exception.
- `push(int)`:   Accepts an integer as it's only argument and pushes it onto the stack, if there is enough memory.
- `size()`:  returns the size of the stack as an integer.
- `toString()`:  returns a string representation of the stack.  For example, if the stack contains `8, 3, 2, 5` with `8` at the top, then this would return `[8, 3, 2, 5]`, formatted exactly like this.

The calculator will need to support the following operations:

- `+` : addition
- `-` : subtraction
- `*` : multiplication
- `/` : division
- `%` : modulus
- `?` : print the current contents of the stack to the screen using the toString() method.
- `^` : pops the top of the stack and displays only the value popped.
- `!` : quits the calculator.

The calculator will continuously read input until ! is entered.  It can read any number of tokens as input (see below).  If there aren't enough integers in the stack to perform a calculation, `#Not enough arguments.` should be displayed.  If anything other than integers or the supported operations is entered, the error message `#Invalid input.` should be displayed, without interrupting the rest of the operations for a particular line of input.

I am having trouble with the toString method. How do I convert the stack of ints to strings?

## My code:

```
//  main.cpp
//  practice2
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
class MyStack
{
private:
    Node *top;  
public:
    MyStack();
    ~MyStack();
    void clear();
    void push(int);
    int pop();
    int size();
    string toString();
    bool isEmpty();
};
MyStack::MyStack()
{
    top = NULL;
};

MyStack::~MyStack()
{
    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
};

void MyStack::push(int d)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;

}
int MyStack::pop()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        int value = top->data;
        Node *oldtop = top;
        top = oldtop->next;
        delete oldtop;
        return value;
    } else
    {
        cout << "stack is empty"; //throw exception
        exit(1);
    }
}

string MyStack::toString()
 {
    //redo later
 };

bool MyStack::isEmpty()
{
    return (top == NULL);
}
int main()
{
    MyStack *s = new MyStack();

    s->push(8);
    s->push(3);
    s->push(2);
    s->push(5);
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

## Expected output:

`toString()`:  returns a string representation of the stack.  For example, if the stack contains `8, 3, 2, 5` with `8` at the top, then this would return `[8, 3, 2, 5]`, formatted exactly like this.

Comment: What you really have to create your "stack" is a simple single-linked list. Getting the values from beginning (top of stack) to end (bottom of stack) is a simple loop.

Comment: Btw., note that the stack you create in the code puts `5` at the top, not `8` (which is at the bottom).

Comment: How do I fix the push function so it puts 8 at the top instead?

Comment: You change the order in which you push the values? The top of a stack is always the last pushed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
string MyStack::toString()
 {
    string result = "[";
    bool needs_comma = false;
    for (Node* temp = top; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next) {
        if (needs_comma) result += ", ";
        needs_comma = true;
        result += std::to_string(temp->data);
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
 };
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I inserted this into my toString method. But it still does not print out anything when I do s->toString() in main

Comment: The `toString` method here just creates a string value, rather than dumping it.  That means that after calling `toString`, the string will be present somewhere in your program's memory, however it will not be present in the terminal output (yet).  In order to print it out, you will have to feed the string value produced by calling `toString` into something like `std::cout`.  Try adding `std::cout << s->toString() << std::endl;` to where after you finish pushing values in your `main`.